# Netbeans C program return value 2

Tags: c, netbeans

I just got my Netbeans tools configured,and (*finally*) it worked :) (I checked with Hello World). We were shifting so I have had like a 3 month gap so I though I'd make a calculator rather than some other program like a palindrome checker and bleh bleh bleh.
So here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
void addition(int,int);
void subtraction(int,int);
void  mutiplication(int,int);
void division(int,int);
int main() {
    int x,y,choice,redo = 1;
    while(redo)
    {
    printf("\nWelcome to the CalC :D\nPlease make a choice\n1.Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4.Division\n>");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice);
    {
    case '1' :
        {
            printf("Enter the first number\n>");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            printf("\nThe second number?\n>");
            scanf("%d",&y);
            addition(x,y);
        }
        case '2' :
        {
            printf("Enter the first number\n>");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            printf("\nThe number to be subtracted from %d is?\n>",x);
            scanf("%d",&y);
            subtraction(x,y);
        }
        case '3' :
        {
            printf("Enter the first number\n>");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            printf("\nThe number to be multiplied with %d is?\n>",x);
            scanf("%d",&y);
            multiplication(x,y);

        }

        case '4' :
        {
            printf("Enter the first number\n>");
            scanf("%d",&x);
            printf("\nThe number to be divided by %d is?\n>",x);
            scanf("%d",&y);
            division(x,y);
        }
    }
    printf("\nWould you like to make another calculation?\n1.Yes '_' \n2.No! :p\n>");
    scanf("%d",&redo);

    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void addition(int x,int y)
{
    int sum;
    sum = x + y;
    printf("\nThe sum of %d and %d is %d\n(Press enter to display the menu)",x,y,sum);
    getch();
}

void subtraction(int x,int y)
{
    int difference;
    ce;
    difference = x - y;
    printf("The difference between %d and %d is %d\n(Press enter to display the        menu)",x,y,difference);
    getch();
}

void multiplication(int x,int y)
{
    int product;
    product = x * y;
    printf("The product of %d and %d is %d\n(Press enter to display the menu)",x,y,product);
    getch();
}

void division(int x,int y)
{
    float quotent;
    quotent = (float)x/(float)y;
    printf("The quotient of %d and %d is %.2f\n(Press enter to display the menu)",x,y,quotent);
    getch();
}
```

And this is the error I get :

```
"/C/MinGW/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CalC'
"c:/MinGW/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/calc.exe
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CalC'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:26:5: error: case label not within a switch statement
main.c:34:9: error: case label not within a switch statement
main.c:42:9: error: case label not within a switch statement
main.c:52:9: error: case label not within a switch statement
main.c: In function 'subtraction':
main.c:78:5: error: 'ce' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:78:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c: At top level:
main.c:83:6: warning: conflicting types for 'multiplication' [enabled by default]
main.c:48:13: note: previous implicit declaration of 'multiplication' was here
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target 'build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CalC'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/CaptFuzzyboots/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CalC'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 661ms)
```

I'm used to code::blocks so I don't really know what's the problem here :\ 
please help me out,I clearly defined the switch labels as '1','2','3','4'!
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is the extra semi-colon after `switch (choice)`. Remove that semi-colon, and be sure to have a `break` after each case as well.

You also have `choice` declared as an integer, but your `case` labels are switching on a `char`; it would be advisable to get rid of the single quotes around each case.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semicolon after `switch(choice)`. Your code has

```
switch(choice);
```

and it should be

```
switch(choice)
```

A few other problems:

1) You misspelled `multiplication` when you defined the function at the top. 
2) There's a stray `ce;` in your `subtraction` function. 
3) You don't have any `break` statements in your `case` statements (it looks like you don't want the cases to fall through, so you probably need them) 
4) `choice` is an `int`, but you're casing on `char`s. Since you're reading ints with `scanf`, you probably want to have `1,2,3,4` instead of `'1','2','3','4'`.

Answer (score 0):

- do case '1' instead of case 1
- write multiplication and not mutiplication
- remove the "ce" from the subtraction function

Comment: Thanks :) 
I have had a 3 month gap( my computer got messed up ) so I'm really out of practice :)

Answer (score 0):

1. remove semicolon after switch(choice)
2. have a 'break' in each case
3. at the begining, correct spelling of multiplication
4. remove "ce;" inside the function subtraction.
5. Change cases '1', '2', etc to 1, 2...
6. Please note that, running a normal C code from Netbeans IDE should produce the same result if you run it in Eclipse or some other IDE. Your error is noway related to Netbeans.